# Mobx Observable object reacting to updates

Tags: object, observable, mobx

I have a mobx observable object:

`@observable friend = {name: 'bert'}`

And I have a mobx action which updates the object:

`@action addAge = () => this.friend.age = 20`

But my `friend` object doesn't update.

I have looked into the mobx docs and it seems `map` may be the correct thing to use because it takes into account new items placed into an object. However this seems to be more tailored to arrays. `extendObservable` seems to be more tailored to classes.

What is good practise for adding to a mobx observable object?

Comment: If you know all the keys beforehand, you can use an object with `null` values, and it will work: `observable friend = { name: 'bert', age: null };`. If the keys can be totally dynamic, you need to use a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map is the correct way to go about changing keys on on a object, as the map creates a `keyed array`.

Map works like the ES6 map in that it can take an iterable.

`@observable friend =  new Map([[ 'name', 'jack']])`

At any point now friend can be modified using set.

`@action addAge = () => {
  this.friend.set('age', 24);
}`

Anything using the friend observable will react to changes in values on existing keys and the addition or removal of new keys.